Filtering out values in bicep ( array )
I pass an array from my param file. This parameter is called "avds". This normally contains objects
This can be either empty: param avds = []
Or this can be an array of AVD objects. For example:
param avds = [
  {
    fslogixShares : [
    ]
    avdSubnetName : 'avd'
    workspaceFriendlyName : 'Workstations'
    maxSessionLimit : 1
    avdIndexNumber : '001'
    hostPoolType : 'Personal'
    desktopAssignmentType : 'Direct'
    startVmOnConnect : true
    loadBalancerType : 'DepthFirst'
    preferredAppGroupType: 'Desktop'
    avdScalingPlanSchedules : [
    ]
    remoteAppApplicationGroups : [
      {
        name: 'Desktop'
      }
    ]
    vdi : {
      amount: 10
      function: 'vdi'
      virtualMachineType: 'workstation'
      fromMarketplace: false
      domainEntraJoin: false
      availabilitySet: {
          name: 'none'
      }
        indexNumber: '01'
        description: 'VDI'
        vmSize: 'Standard_NV6ads_A10_v5'
        serviceLevel: '1'
        backupRetention: 'backup-week'
        disks: {
          osDisk: {
            imageOffer: 'windows-11'
            imagePublisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop'
            imageSku: 'win11-23h2-pro'
            osDiskSizeGb: 256
            osDiskSku: 'Premium_LRS'
            osType: 'Windows'
            skuVersion: 'latest'
          }
          dataDisks: [
          ]
        }
        nics: [
          {
            indexNumber: '01'
            vnet: 'shared'
            subnet: 'avd'
            enableIPForwarding: false
            ipConfigurations: [
              {
                privateIpAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
                privateIpAddress: ''
                publicIp: false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]

What i want to do is:

Filter the array. It can not contain the avd.vdi property.
If it contains the value pass it towards an array or a bool.

I tried to do it via this way:
var avdsWithVdi = [for avd in avds: (!empty(avd.vdi)) ? true : false]
var anyAvdHasVdi = contains(avdsWithVdi, true)

I run of the array. If its empty return false also return false when the value vdi is not present.
I also tried to use outputs but that doesnt get me any results.
I am trying to use this value then to add this to 1 of my modules to let it run or not.
module prodRgDeployHostPoolId 'br/nubesmodules:bicep/modules/resourcegroupnt:latest' = if (anyAvdHasVdi) {
  name: 'prod_deploy_abbr-id_func-avd_hostpoolcreator-${iteration}'
  params: {
    function: 'hostpooltoken'
    indexNumber: '001'
    location: location
    environment: environment
    resourceDescription: 'This resource group contains a managed identity that has hostPoolCreator rights Required for deployment scripts.'
    iteration: iteration
  }
}

The error is
prod_deploy_abbr-id_func-avd_hostpoolcreator-nan Deployment NotFound(Error details) Operation


Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve ? Also do you have a sample of the desired output ? Thanks a lot

Hi tHomas,
Yes. I just explained it at the bottom. Thanks in advance !

What is the error you are getting here. @BGB

Problem is that the output doesnt work. I tried it
output number1 array = avdsWithVdi
output number2 bool = anyAvdHasVdi
It still runs over this module for some odd reason ( the module for the hostpool creator )


Filtering out values in bicep ( array ):

Firstly, I have tried to execute the way you used the conditional loop withcontains and !empty functions, I was able to check the outputs block clearly as shown below.
var avdsWithVdi = [for avd in avds: (!empty(avd.vdi)) ? true : false]
var anyAvdHasVdi = contains(avdsWithVdi, true)
output avdsWithVdi array = avdsWithVdi
output anyAvdHasVdi bool = anyAvdHasVdi



Alternatively, you can try using length() function for checking the avdsWithVdi array has any elements stored using length(avdsWithVdi) > 0 condition and keep the avdsWithVdi for () loop as you already used.
Note: Or you can also use !contains() function in for loop if still the issue persists with an empty() function.
I tried to deploy host pools with the below modified code according to your requirement and was able to deploy it successfully.
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param avds array = [
  {
    fslogixShares : [
    ]
    avdSubnetName : 'avd'
    workspaceFriendlyName : 'Workstations'
    maxSessionLimit : 1
    avdIndexNumber : '001'
    hostPoolType : 'Personal'
    desktopAssignmentType : 'Direct'
    startVmOnConnect : true
    loadBalancerType : 'DepthFirst'
    preferredAppGroupType: 'Desktop'
    avdScalingPlanSchedules : [
    ]
    remoteAppApplicationGroups : [
      {
        name: 'Desktop'
      }
    ]
    vdi : {
      amount: 10
      function: 'vdi'
      virtualMachineType: 'workstation'
      fromMarketplace: false
      domainEntraJoin: false
      availabilitySet: {
          name: 'none'
      }
        indexNumber: '01'
        description: 'VDI'
        vmSize: 'Standard_NV6ads_A10_v5'
        serviceLevel: '1'
        backupRetention: 'backup-week'
        disks: {
          osDisk: {
            imageOffer: 'windows-11'
            imagePublisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop'
            imageSku: 'win11-23h2-pro'
            osDiskSizeGb: 256
            osDiskSku: 'Premium_LRS'
            osType: 'Windows'
            skuVersion: 'latest'
          }
          dataDisks: [
          ]
        }
        nics: [
          {
            indexNumber: '01'
            vnet: 'shared'
            subnet: 'avd'
            enableIPForwarding: false
            ipConfigurations: [
              {
                privateIpAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
                privateIpAddress: ''
                publicIp: false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
var avdsWithVdi = [for avd in avds: (!empty(avd.vdi)) ? true : false]
var anyAvdHasVdi = length(avdsWithVdi) > 0
output avdsWithVdi array = avdsWithVdi
output anyAvdHasVdi bool = anyAvdHasVdi
param hostPoolName string = 'newpooln'
resource hostPool 'Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostPools@2019-12-10-preview' = if(anyAvdHasVdi)  {
  name: hostPoolName
  location: location
  properties: {
    hostPoolType: 'Personal'
    loadBalancerType: 'DepthFirst'
    //customRdpProperty: 
    preferredAppGroupType: 'Desktop'
    personalDesktopAssignmentType: 'Automatic'
    validationEnvironment: false
  }
}




so my supplied code works for you ?
The problem is when i deploy with avds = [] empty. It still tries to enter the module from hostpool
Then i get the error that it can not find the deployment:
prod_deploy_abbr-id_func-avd_hostpoolcreator-nan
Deployment
NotFound(Error details)
Operation details

Can you try passing the condition in this way once. [for avd in avds: if (empty(avd.vdi)) ? false : avd] @BGB

Hi. Just tried it. It always want to still try this module for a reason.
Also. I have other modules that have the same check. It doesnt start those.
So it tries to start the hostpoolcreator module. but for example the module straight after it. With the same check for the AnyAvdHasVdi it doesnt try to start that one

Are you checking this condition if(anyAvdHasVdi) correctly? @BGB

These are the modules:
https://pastebin.com/4FFS1HRT
As you can see. yes. So module 1 gets called but immediatly throws an error:
prod_deploy_abbr-id_func-avd_hostpoolcreator-nan
Deployment
NotFound(Error details)
Operation details

That is a transient issue. Can you change the resource names and check the parameters passing again. @BGB

Im not really sure i understand what you mean. What resource names do i need to change ?

Can you try a new deployment instead of running in old one. @BGB

I am running always new deployments from 1 big file. And the deployment name is always different. main-hour-minute-seconds

Did you try clearing the cache history and deploy. @BGB

Because for me it worked fine.

what do you mean with cache history ? I cleared the cache of my modules. and the deployments on my test sub.

If I deploy the similar configuration, I am getting successful results with no issues. That is why I am asking you to check the deployment history as other deployments might causing the issue. What is your platform of execution. @BGB

I use visual studio code windows to deploy. So i right click on my main bicep file which contains all my core modules. i select location and my param file and it deploys towards my selected sub.
It also happens when we deploy via pipelines in azure devops

Ok so can you try removing a module just for hostpool creator and keep the resource hostpool configuration. Try calling it directly. So that we can be able to figure it out if is with the module or the whole resource. @BGB

the same thing happens again. this is very weird behaviour :(

This must indeed be something caching wise.
When i run this pure with another hardcoded value like value : false. It still tries this value.

ya this is related to a cache issue. Can you try deployment in Azure CLI once? @BGB

yes. i have the same thing then aswell. :(

Change the path of current working directory and try it in a new folder once. Lets check! @BGB

so i copied my entire codebase to another folder. everything just to be sure. closed down my vscode just to be sure. and now ill run it from az cli

Is it working now? @BGB

New main bicep file. New folder. new parameter folder. same thing.. ill guess ill leave it :(

If everything is new and still not able to achieve the success deployment, it could be definitely some backend environment issue. Have you tried restarting the CLI. @BGB

Its even happening on our pipelines end

Can you copy and paste the error in above question once. @BGB

I have copied the error
